# Accesing values in xml file with namespaces in python 2.7 lxml

Tags: python, namespaces, lxml

I'm following this link to try to get values of several tags:

[Parsing XML with namespace in Python via 'ElementTree'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14853243/parsing-xml-with-namespace-in-python-via-elementtree)

In this link there is no problem to access to the root tag like this:

```
import sys
from lxml import etree as ET


doc = ET.parse('file.xml')

namespaces_rdf = {'rdf': 'http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#'} # add more as needed
namespaces_dcat = {'dcat': 'http://www.w3.org/ns/dcat#'} # add more as needed
namespaces_dct = {'dct': 'http://purl.org/dc/terms/'}

print doc.findall('rdf:RDF', namespaces_rdf)
print doc.findall('dcat:Dataset', namespaces_dcat)
print doc.findall('dct:identifier', namespaces_dct)
```

OUTPUT:

```
[]
[<Element {http://www.w3.org/ns/dcat#}Dataset at 0x2269b98>]
[]
```

I get only access to dcat:Dataset, and I can't see how to access the value of rdf:about

And later access to dct:identifier

Of course, once I have accessed to this info, I need to acces to dcat:distribution info

This is my example file, generated with ckanext-dcat:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rdf:RDF
  xmlns:dct="http://purl.org/dc/terms/"
  xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
  xmlns:dcat="http://www.w3.org/ns/dcat#"
>
  <dcat:Dataset rdf:about="http://www.myweb.com/dataset/ec631628-2f46-4f17-a685-d62a37466c01">
    <dct:identifier>ec631628-2f46-4f17-a685-d62a37466c01</dct:identifier>
    <dct:description>FOO-Description</dct:description>
    <dct:title>FOO-title</dct:title>
    <dcat:keyword>keyword1</dcat:keyword>
    <dcat:keyword>keyword2</dcat:keyword>
    <dct:issued rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime">2014-10-08T08:55:04.566618</dct:issued>
    <dct:modified rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime">2015-06-25T11:04:10.328902</dct:modified>
    <dcat:distribution>
      <dcat:Distribution rdf:about="http://www.myweb.com/dataset/ec631628-2f46-4f17-a685-d62a37466c01/resource/f5707551-6bf3-468f-9a96-b4184cc51d1f">
        <dct:title>FOO-title-1</dct:title>
        <dct:description>FOO-Description-1</dct:description>
        <dcat:accessURL>http://www.myweb.com/dataset/ec631628-2f46-4f17-a685-d62a37466c01/resource/f5707551-6bf3-468f-9a96-b4184cc51d1f/download/myxls.xls</dcat:accessURL>
        <dct:format>XLS</dct:format>
      </dcat:Distribution>
    </dcat:distribution>
    <dcat:distribution>
      <dcat:Distribution rdf:about="http://www.myweb.com/dataset/ec631628-2f46-4f17-a685-d62a37466c01/resource/74c1acc8-b2b5-441b-afb2-d072d0d00a7f">
        <dct:format>XLS</dct:format>
        <dct:title>FOO-title-2</dct:title>
        <dct:description>FOO-Description-2</dct:description>
        <dcat:accessURL>http://www.myweb.com/dataset/ec631628-2f46-4f17-a685-d62a37466c01/resource/74c1acc8-b2b5-441b-afb2-d072d0d00a7f/download/myxls.xls</dcat:accessURL>
      </dcat:Distribution>
    </dcat:distribution>
  </dcat:Dataset>
</rdf:RDF>
```

Any idea on how to access this info??
Thanks

UPDATE:
Well, I need to access **rdf:about** in:

```
<dcat:Dataset rdf:about="http://www.myweb.com/dataset/ec631628-2f46-4f17-a685-d62a37466c01">
```

so with this code taken from:

[Parse xml with lxml - extract element value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12657043/parse-xml-with-lxml-extract-element-value)

```
for node in doc.xpath('//dcat:Dataset', namespaces=namespaces):
   # Iterate over attributes
   for attrib in node.attrib:
            print '@' + attrib + '=' + node.attrib[attrib]
```

I get this output:

```
[<Element {http://www.w3.org/ns/dcat#}Dataset at 0x23d8ee0>]
@{http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#}about=http://www.myweb.com/dataset/ec631628-2f46-4f17-a685-d62a37466c01
```

So, the question is:

How can I ask if the attribute is **about** to take this value, because in other files I have several tags.

UPDATE 2: Fixed how I get about value (clark notations)

```
for node in doc.xpath('//dcat:Dataset', namespaces=namespaces):
   # Iterate over attributes
   for attrib in node.attrib:
      if attrib.endswith('about'):
        #do my jobs
```

**Well, almost finished, but I have last question: I need to know when I access my**

`<dct:title>`

to which belongs, I have:

```
<dcat:Dataset rdf:about="http://www.myweb.com/dataset/ec631628-2f46-4f17-a685-d62a37466c01">
       <dct:title>FOO-title</dct:title>

<dcat:Distribution rdf:about="http://www.myweb.com/dataset/ec631628-2f46-4f17-a685-d62a37466c01/resource/f5707551-6bf3-468f-9a96-b4184cc51d1f">
        <dct:title>FOO-title-1</dct:title>

<dcat:Distribution rdf:about="http://www.myweb.com/dataset/ec631628-2f46-4f17-a685-d62a37466c01/resource/74c1acc8-b2b5-441b-afb2-d072d0d00a7f">
        <dct:title>FOO-title-2</dct:title>
```

If I do something like this I get:

```
for node in doc.xpath('//dct:title', namespaces=namespaces):
   print node.tag, node.text

{http://purl.org/dc/terms/}title FOO-title
{http://purl.org/dc/terms/}title FOO-title-1
{http://purl.org/dc/terms/}title FOO-title-2
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `xpath()` method with `namespaces` named argument:

```
namespaces = {
    'rdf': 'http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#',
    'dcat': 'http://www.w3.org/ns/dcat#',
    'dct': 'http://purl.org/dc/terms/'
}

print(doc.xpath('//rdf:RDF', namespaces=namespaces))
print(doc.xpath('//dcat:Dataset', namespaces=namespaces))
print(doc.xpath('//dct:identifier', namespaces=namespaces))
```

Comment: Well, Great!!!, works like a charm, I didn't know xpath, so I take a time to understand it. Thanks